# Apple tree concerns

Tags: diagnosis, fruit-trees, diseases, pruning, apples

I purchased a house with an apple tree, maybe 15' tall and 6" in diameter. The tree has two longer branches and I was wondering how to go about trimming them. If anyone can tell me where to make the cuts that would be appreciated. Also, if anyone can spot other problem areas and let me know, that would be appreciated. I plan on applying an orchard fertilizer as soon as the weather warms up. Thank you.

-note: My pictures are not uploading, I require some assistance.

Comment: Hey! Loading pictures should be fairly straight forward. There is a picture looking icon that you will click. It will allow you to browse your computer for the pictures or input an html that is hosting your images. Were you able to find this icon? Perhaps you did find the icon but it reported an error? Please elaborate.

Comment: Pictures would be very useful. However, it is now too late to prune apples but we can give you the right advice on pruning when the dormant season returns

Comment: A common issue when uploading photos from a cell phone is they are too large, You might need to change the resolution to get a smaller picture

Comment: Calm the urge to fertilize willy-nilly. "Too late to prune" is debatable - for trees that have been let go and need major work, some of that major work can be done any time other than a couple months before frost. "Normal" pruning is done in the dormant season, yes, but if the trees turn out to have a massive crop of watersprouts, you can just whack those off - and it's always fine to cut out dead wood - also, without knowing your location and how warm the weather has not gotten yet, perhaps you are writing from a region where it's still dormant season...